# Изменение цвета LineRenderer в реальном времени Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Идея в следующем: если игрок двигает поплавок удочки к краю допустимой области, леска, реализованная при помощи LineRenderer постепенно становится красной, и, соответственно, если поплавок смещается к центру этой области, то леска опять становится черного цвета. Становилась бы. Но, почему-то при моем решении леска просто сразу же становится красной и больше не меняет цвет:

```
float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, fishZone.position);
float pr = (dist / 0.0099f);
Color c = new Color(255 / 100 * pr, 0, 0, 1);
rend.material.color = c;
```

При этом если выводить значение rend.material.color в консоль, то можно увидеть, что оно изменяется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому я не понимаю, почему в самой игре цвет не меняется?

Comment: А разве цвет в диапазоне от 0 до 255? Попробуй интерполировать от 0 до 1